# Turning a line from a java scanner(file) into an array

Tags: java

All I am writting a simple java method that reads a text file of place names and will then map them to some characteristics...

This is the first time in java that I have read from a file.

I have written the code below that works - it reads the first line.

But what I want to do is to turn this line into a character array so that I can compare each character to a unsorted file and then map the words.

But I am struggling with a very basic challenge.  How do I map the sc.scanner to a character array

Or should I use BufferReader

```
       File file = new File ("c:/Users/Green/documents/places.txt");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

       //   while (sc.hasNextLine())

               System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

Comment: Scanner's nextLine() basically returns a string which is something like an array of characters. You can access any char with the atChar() method. I haven't understood what mapping are you trying to achieve. Could you please provide what the text looks like and what result do you want?

Comment: Do you want to read the while file into an char[] or do you want to read it line by line and split words by some rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method of String which is `toCharArray()`.

See the [String documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()).

Answer (score 0):

As documented the method Scanner.[nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) returns a String, you can transform it to a character array using String.[tocharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) and after iterate over it like below:

```
String line = sc.nextLine();
char[] arr = line.toCharArray();
for (char ch: arr) {
  ...here your logic
}
```